# Вылетает приложение при запуске на телефоне

Tags: android

Подскажите пож-та,почему вылетает приложение. Я только учусь работать в Android Studio, пытаюсь использовать imageButton с изображением формата SVG.Если сделать обычную кнопку, то всё работает правильно. Вот это пишется в Logcat

```
03-07 19:41:51.674 1581-1581/com.example.probasvg E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.probasvg, PID: 1581
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.probasvg/com.example.probasvg.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
        at com.example.probasvg.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Не ставьте метку android-studio. Этот вопрос к ней не относится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно в классе вместо строки:

```
Button button;
```

написать:

```
ImageButton imgButton;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогли

Comment: Если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, то отметьте его как принятый :)